# Slider Minimum / Maximum binding to Int constant

Tags: wpf, data-binding, types, slider, converters

I have an integer constants to define minimum and maximum values of some integer data, and i want to bind them to a Slider control properties like im doing on another numeric editor, but seems impossible.

Is there any easy way to acomplish this? Maybe with value converters, or Im missing something?

A bit of example code:

```
public const Int32 EXAMPLE_MIN_VALUE = 23;
public const Int32 EXAMPLE_MAX_VALUE = 55;
```

This works ok, im using an integer editor of WpfToolkit:

```
<WpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding ExampleValue}" 
    Minimum="{x:Static Model:Configuracion.EXAMPLE_MIN_VALUE}" 
    Maximum="{x:Static Model:Configuracion.EXAMPLE_MAX_VALUE}" />
```

But when I try the same with Slider, it crash:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding ExampleValue}" 
    Minimum="{x:Static Model:Configuracion.EXAMPLE_MIN_VALUE}" 
    Maximum="{x:Static Model:Configuracion.EXAMPLE_MAX_VALUE}" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x:Static` instead of `Binding` on the Min/Max of the slider?

Comment: Ouch, you are right, i made a mistake when copying from my tests. Fixed now ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `x:Static` directly that has no room for type conversion and thus causes an exception as you try to set an int on a double-property, but if you do this it works just fine:

```xml
Minimum="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.TestConstInt}}"
```

That is because bindings apply type converters where necessary. And even if there were no suitable type converter you could just add a [`Binding.Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx).

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks for the answer, XAML have a lot of things that i need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This is the error message that comes up:
{"'23' is not a valid value for property 'Minimum'."}

Change the constant binding to double and it should work!

```
public const double EXAMPLE_MIN_VALUE = 23.0;
public const double EXAMPLE_MAX_VALUE = 55.0;
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that i wanted to use the same constant with another control that only accepts integer values, nevermind, H.B. answer works ;).

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding doesn't work with fields, only with properties.

Take a look, you have:

```
Minimum="{x:Static Model:Configuracion.EXAMPLE_MIN_VALUE}"
```

In the first example and:

```
Minimum="{Binding Model:Configuracion.EXAMPLE_MIN_VALUE}"
```

Comment: The problem is that the value im binding is a constant, i did it like i saw on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) or [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232986/xaml-binding-textbox-maxlength-to-class-constant) ;). As i said, the first one is working, the problem is that im trying to bind a Int value to a double property i think.